# Get newly inserted row ID from Oracle Output parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, rowid

I am trying to add a new row in oracle and get the ID of the newly inserted row, here is what my code looks like

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into table1 (id,col2) values (id_seq.NEXTVAL,'abc') returning id into :new_id";

OracleParameter objParameter = new OracleParameter("new_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
objParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(objParameter);

cmd.Connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

newID = objParameter.Value;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should specify what errors etc you are getting

Comment: I am not getting any errors and the insert is working as well. The only issue is that the objParameter does not have the newly inserted id.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing the insert query to:

```
insert into table1 (id,col2) values (id_seq.NEXTVAL,'abc') returning id into new_id
```